# C++: Add a dll directory while runtime

Tags: c++, qt, dll, msdn

I want to use Qt in my Application.
It should be a single exe file that is self extracting something.
Because I want to use Qt I wanted to extract the Qt libs to a temporary directory
and add them while running. They shouldn't be extracted to the exe path.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to change working directory e.g. `cwd("newdir")` or `SetCurrentDirectory("newdir")`.

Another is to modify your process $PATH, e.g. `putenv ("PATH", "path + newdir")`.